# Auto Start and Stop EOSIO blockchain nodeos

Tags: nodeos, blockchains, ubuntu

I have a private EOS blockchain setup with peer nodes connected. If any problem occurs and the server gets shut down the **nodeos** gets stopped (sometimes normally sometimes with dirty flag type errors). And every time I need to restart it manually. Instead, I need that it should get restart as soon as the server gets on. How would I do this? I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodeos requires that it is shutdown cleanly.  Make sure you allow enough time for the state to be written to disk. On a big blockchain with a slow disk, shutdown could take a minute or more.

If you don't shutdown cleanly, then you will need to replay the chain from scratch to rebuild the state or or use a previously saved state snapshot file.  More details can be found here: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/v2.0/nodeos/replays/index

To have nodeos start when the server starts, create a systemd unit file or update /etc/rc.local or whatever is your preference for managing system services.

Comment: My eosio setup is the same as https://developers.eos.io/welcome/v2.0/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence with multiple peers running. Can you please help me with how to create ```systemd``` unit file for my blockchain? Or any reference link?

Answer (score 0):

I create `systemd` service file as below for running the `biosboot` setup files to stop and start nodeos:

```
[Unit]
Description=Stop and Start the eos blockchain
After=network.target shutdown.target reboot.target
[Service]
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/home/user/biosboot/genesis/stop.sh
ExecStart=/home/user/biosboot/genesis/start.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/biosboot/genesis
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service stops the nodeos before the server shutdown/restart and starts after the server gets on.